# Получить данные из active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

есть самая обычная WinForms(С#) на которой есть два TextBox или lables. 
в одну форму нужно выводить Имя пользователя компьютера 
во вторую его номер телефона из active directory.
подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?
нашел кучу статей но что-то ни одна так не помогла.
или ткните пальцем куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
PrincipalContext ADContextGeneral = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADContextGeneral, Environment.UserName);

string phone = user.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
string displayName = user.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Спасибо! но все равно не получается у меня добавлено `using System.DirectoryServices`;
и вместо 
`PrincipalContext ADContextGeneral = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADContextGeneral, Environment.UserName);`
я должен использовать: `DirectoryEntry CurrentDomain = new DirectoryEntry();`
я правильно понимаю? или что-то опять запутался?

Comment: Добавьте из проекта ссылку на сборку: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Укажите в using пространство имен: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Вставьте код из ответа и проверьте, работает он или нет.